# Jquery Select Menu height

Tags: jquery

I am trying this example: http://jqueryui.com/selectmenu/

in JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3b1htdfr/5/

```
 $(function () {
 $("#number")
     .selectmenu()
     .selectmenu("menuWidget")
     .addClass("overflow");
 });
```

but the selectmenu is about double the *height* that is shown on the jqueryui example page. How do I change the height of the select menu? I have tried height, padding, margin, font size. Nothing seems to change it.

Comment: Fixed, sorry. It is height.

Comment: What browser are you using? To me it looks the same in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

thats because jQuery selectmenu creates a custom select made of divs and spans. your original select with `id=number` is hidden.

you need to add your classes to the relevant parts of the newly created menu;

- The part that you click to let the menu drop down is called the **"Button"**
- The part that drops down and has all the list items is called **"Menu"**

```js
$(function() {
  $("#number").selectmenu();
  $("#number").data("ui-selectmenu").button.addClass("SelectButton")
  $("#number").data("ui-selectmenu").menu.addClass("SelectMenu");
});
```

```css
.SelectButton {
  width: 200px !important;
  font-size: 12px !important;
  color: red !important;
}
.SelectMenu {
  width: 200px !important;
  font-size: 10px !important;
  color: blue !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<span>
    <select name="number" id="number">
        <option>1</option>
        <option selected="selected">2</option>
        <option>3</option>
        <option>4</option>
        <option>5</option>
        <option>6</option>
        <option>7</option>
        <option>8</option>
        <option>9</option>
        <option>10</option>
        <option>11</option>
        <option>12</option>
        <option>13</option>
        <option>14</option>
        <option>15</option>
        <option>16</option>
        <option>17</option>
        <option>18</option>
        <option>19</option>
    </select>
</span>
```

Comment: Thank you for that. Do you know what the other parts of the selectmenu are named so that they can be modified? With your code the width is now too small.

Comment: the list part of the menu will have a `-menu` suffix. the width is small because it is overriden by the selectmenu widget. you need to use custom rendering/sizing to change it, or force change it after the widget loads

Comment: .selectmenu({
         width: 200
     }) made it wider

Comment: @user3335229 i have updated the answer with more appropriate solution